# OpenSSL verify succeeds but server certificate validation failed

Tags: ssl, openssl

I created a CA certificate and another certificate with cfssl.  The agent certificate seems to  verify with openssl:

```
$ openssl verify -verbose -x509_strict -CAfile ca_cert.pem -CApath nosuchdir agent_cert.pem
agent_cert.pem: OK
```

However, when I write a simple client/server, I get the error:

```
4106024700:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed:s3_clnt.c:1063:
```

I am calling SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations and setting the certificates on both sides using:

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(
    sslCtx(),"./agent_cert.pem",
    SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(
    sslCtx(),"./agent_privkey.pem",
    SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(
    sslCtx(),"./ca_cert.pem",
    NULL);
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: You reverse the private key and cert? It should be `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(
    sslCtx(),"./agent_cert.pem",
    SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);` and `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(
    sslCtx(),"./agent_privkey.pem",
    SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);`?

Comment: Checking the result of the functions you use might help in finding bugs like noticed by jfly.

Comment: Unfortunately that was just a mistake in my post, not the code itself.  I have checked the results and they all are successful.

Comment: What is the URL to the server or the server's name? Also see [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.